# Switching inputs on my monitor requires me to unplug and replug my MacBook Air USB-C Cable

Tags: macbook-pro, display, catalina, usb

My monitor has 2 inputs, an HDMI input (which is plugged into my Windows machine) and a USB-C input (which is plugged into my Macboook Air). I switch between these inputs often, but everytime I switch into to the USB-C input mode mode (which again, is plugged to my macbook) it blanks the screen. I need to unplug and replug the usb-c cable to get the screen working.

When I switch inputs to the Windows Machine, it works consistently. I can switch back and forth between HDMI and USB-C, and the HDMI mode will always show my Windows Desktop. It's just the USB-C input that's troublesome. Switching out of USB-C to HDMI, and then back again causes the screen to just blank.

Mac recognizes the two displays however, but my monitor just says there's no USB-C input. I need to manually unplug and replug the cable each time I switch inputs for it to work as expected.

Additionally, The USB-C cable from my monitor charges my macbook and provide additional USB ports, all of which work fine. It's just the video feed that drops each time

Comment: It’s the same issue, you just have multiple computers hooked up to the monitor simultaneously. You need an active adapter because the clock sync  gets “out if sync” and the Mac video driver doesn’t know how to cope.

Comment: @Allan I'm not using an adapter at all, or changing signals like in that question. The monitor has a direct USB-C connection to my macbook (it's a USB-C monitor)

Comment: You said , “if you switch out of USB-C to HDMI and back, the screen stays blank.”  Can you clarify?

Comment: My monitor has 2 inputs, an HDMI input (which is plugged into my Windows machine) and a USB-C input (which is plugged into my macbook). I switch between these inputs often, but everytime I switch into my USB-C mode (which is plugged to my macbook) it blanks the screen. I need to unplug and replug the usb-c cable.

I'm not using any adapters

Comment: The way it’s written is confusing.  If you’re going USB-C to USB-C then it’s DisplayPort to DisplayPort.  I retracted my close vote

Comment: Rewrote the question to be more readable